# I have a HP pavillion dv9000 and its all messed up, an invalid windows 7, so I purchaced a restore disk. Now what do I do?

Tags: restore

I have a Hp pavilion dv9000 and wish to restore it to its new condition. I have a restore disk- what do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would first start by finding the documentation about restoring from the disk from HP's website or anything that came with it.

I would suspect that all you have to do is put the disk in and follow the on screen instructions. If nothing happens, try rebooting the machine *with* the disk still in the drive.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to recover that laptop,

1.) use F11 at the HP logo screen during boot to launch recovery manager.

2.) Boot from disc 1 of the recovery discs to start the recovery process.

Windows 7

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01895783&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

.

Vista

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00809678&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

This is assuming your original OS was Vista or Windows 7, not some earlier version.